# How can I check why component disappears when I add it to placeholder?

Tags: powershell-extensions

when I add `content` that was previously generated to `placeholder` of page, the whole component disappears, how can I check where is there error, also the content was created on new language version by `PowerShell` script.

Comment: did you see the page in experience editor as well?

Comment: Yes, but not the components.

Comment: Are you able to debug your component?

Comment: No, I am on PROD

Answer (score 2):

When I have had to debug a similar issue in the past (generated layout that would not display) I used the Content Editor. From there, you can use the Presentation Details dialog to see all the components and which placeholders they were added to. You can also see the raw XML of the layout, if you really need to.

This can help you debug if the components were not added, or were added to the wrong placeholder name.